# pipenv: Permission denied for ~/.local/share/virtualenvs

Tags: python, macos, pipenv

I'm working with a codebase that uses pipenv to install dependencies as part of its setup. However, I'm getting the following error when the `pipenv install --deploy --dev` command is run:

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/XXX/.local/share/virtualenvs'`

I've checked the `.local/share` folder and it does not contain a `virtualenvs` folder. Also, the entire `.local` folder is owned by `root`.

Tool versions:

- python - 3.11.7
- pip - 24.0
- pipenv - 2023.12.0

I tried sudo creating a 'virtualenvs' folder in there, but it didn't help... still permission denied. Very reluctant to `chown` a directory that I don't understand the security scope of.

Comment: There should be no security consequences as .local is your own HOME directory. Your .local being owned by `root` is more problematic.

Comment: Nothing in your home directory needs to be owned by `root`. They were probably created by a command unnecessarily executed with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by Philippe and chepner, I decided to change the ownership of my `~/.local/` folder. For surety's sake, I used the `id` command to check my username and group. On MacOS, I guess the group is always `staff`. Then I just used the command:

`sudo chown -R joshuasullivan:staff ~/.local`

And everything started working properly.